# Android NullPointerException error. How to resolve?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

Well I have created an application where there is a Alert Dialog in the program. In the code, it doesn't display an error. But when I run it, I see this Null pointer exception error. I tried resolving it but still not working. What I am trying to do is, when a user clicks the Delete button, there will be an alert dialog saying "Are you sure you want to delete the selected item?" And when the user clicks "Yes" it will be deleted and if "No", it will not be deleted.

Here is my code:

Main activity file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pass_list);
        hideKeyboard();
        initializing();
        show_list_layout();
        Button logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        Toast.makeText(PasswordActivity.this,  "Welcome " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PasswordActivity.this, LogIn.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);
            }
        });

        btn_del.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void btn_addnew_click(View v){
        this.selected_website = null;
        show_add_layout();
    }

    public void btn_back_click(View v){
        this.selected_website = null;
        show_list_layout();
    }

    public void btn_edit_click(View v){
        if(this.selected_website != null){
            show_add_layout();
        }else{
            show_mesg("Please select item to edit.");
        }
    }

    public void btn_add_update_click(View v){
        hideKeyboard();
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        String str_sitename = this.edt_sitename.getText().toString();
        String str_username = this.edt_username.getText().toString();
        String str_password = this.edt_password.getText().toString();
        if (str_sitename.equals("")){
            //edt_sitename.requestFocus();
            show_mesg("Please insert sitename.");
        }else if (str_username.equals("")){
            //edt_username.requestFocus();
            show_mesg("Please insert username.");
        }else if (str_password.equals("")){
            //edt_password.requestFocus();
            show_mesg("Please insert password.");
        }else{
            if (selected_website!=null){
                selected_website.setUser(username);
                selected_website.setSitename(str_sitename);
                selected_website.setUsername(str_username);
                selected_website.setPassword(str_password);
                datasource.updateWebsite(selected_website);
                show_mesg(str_sitename + " updated.");
                hideKeyboard();
                selected_website = null;
                show_list_layout();
            }else{
                datasource.addWebsite(username, str_sitename,str_username,str_password);
                hideKeyboard();
                show_mesg(str_sitename + " added.");
                selected_website = null;
                show_add_layout();
            }
        }
    }

    public void popUps(){
        if(this.selected_website != null){


            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                private WebsiteRecords selected_website;

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        datasource.deleteWebsite(this.selected_website);
                        hideKeyboard();
                        show_mesg(this.selected_website.getSitename() + " deleted.");
                        selected_website = null;
                        show_list_layout();

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        show_mesg("NO");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?")
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                   .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
                   .show();
        }
        else{
                show_mesg("Please select item to delete.");
        }
    }

    /*public void btn_del_click(View v){
         if(this.selected_website != null){
            datasource.deleteWebsite(this.selected_website);
            hideKeyboard();
            show_mesg(this.selected_website.getSitename() + " deleted.");
            selected_website = null;
            show_list_layout();
        }else{
            show_mesg("Please select item to delete.");
        }
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    show_mesg("YES");
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    show_mesg("NO");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener);
    }*/
    public class select_item_click implements OnClickListener{
        private RadioButton rdb_select_item;
        private WebsiteRecords website;
        select_item_click(RadioButton rdb_select_item,WebsiteRecords website){
            this.rdb_select_item = rdb_select_item;
            this.website = website;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i< all_radiobutton.size();i++){
                RadioButton rdb_select_item = all_radiobutton.get(i);
                rdb_select_item.setChecked(false);
            }

            selected_website = this.website;
            this.rdb_select_item.setChecked(true);

        }

    }
    public void hideKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    public void show_add_layout(){
        hideKeyboard();
        LinearLayout layout_list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_list);
        LinearLayout layout_add = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_edit);
        layout_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layout_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (selected_website != null){
            this.edt_sitename.setText(selected_website.getSitename());
            this.edt_username.setText(selected_website.getUsername());
            this.edt_password.setText(selected_website.getPassword());
            this.btn_add.setText("Update");
        }else{
            this.edt_sitename.setText("");
            this.edt_username.setText("");
            this.edt_password.setText("");
            this.edt_sitename.requestFocus();
            this.btn_add.setText("Add");
        }
    }
    public void show_mesg(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void show_list_layout(){
        hideKeyboard();
        LinearLayout layout_list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_list);
        LinearLayout layout_add = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_add_edit);
        layout_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        this.tmp_websites = datasource.getAllWebsite(getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME"));
        Log.i("algo","Cantid ad de web sites "+this.tmp_websites.size());
        this.all_radiobutton.clear();
        ListView showlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListWebsite);
        showlist.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        showlist.setAdapter(new WebsiteItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, this.tmp_websites));
    }

    public class WebsiteItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WebsiteRecords> {
        private List<WebsiteRecords> websites;
        public WebsiteItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<WebsiteRecords> websites) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, websites);
            this.websites = websites;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            hideKeyboard();
            WebsiteRecords website = websites.get(position);
            if (website != null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
                hideKeyboard();
                RadioButton rdb_select_item =(RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rdb_select_item);
                LinearLayout layout_item = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_item);
                TextView tv_sitename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website);
                TextView tv_username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
                TextView tv_password = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
                tv_sitename.setText(website.getSitename());
                tv_username.setText("Username  : " + website.getUsername() );
                tv_password.setText("Password : " + website.getPassword());

                if(selected_website != null){
                    if (selected_website.getId() == website.getId()) rdb_select_item.setChecked(true);
                }

                all_radiobutton.add(rdb_select_item);
                rdb_select_item.setOnClickListener(new select_item_click(rdb_select_item,website));
                layout_item.setOnClickListener(new select_item_click(rdb_select_item,website));
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btn_del) {
            if(this.selected_website != null){
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                private WebsiteRecords selected_website;
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        datasource.deleteWebsite(this.selected_website);
                        hideKeyboard();
                        show_mesg(this.selected_website.getSitename() + " deleted.");
                        selected_website = null;
                        show_list_layout();
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        show_mesg("NO");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?")
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                   .setNegativeButton("NO", dialogClickListener)
                   .show();
            show_mesg("PASSED");
        }
        else{
                show_mesg("Please select item to delete.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My datasource file:

```
public class DataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { 
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_URL,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD
            };

    public DataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void addWebsite(String user, String sitename, String username, String password) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER,  user);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_URL, sitename);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);
        database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL, null,values);
    }

public void updateWebsite(WebsiteRecords website){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_URL, website.getSitename());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME, website.getUsername());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD, website.getPassword());
        database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID  + " = " + website.getId(), null);
    }

public void deleteWebsite(WebsiteRecords website) {
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID  + " = " + website.getId(), null);

}

public List<WebsiteRecords> getAllWebsite(String user){

    List<WebsiteRecords> websites = new ArrayList<WebsiteRecords>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + " WHERE user='" + user+"'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        WebsiteRecords website = cursorToWebsite(cursor);
        websites.add(website);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();

    return websites;
}

private WebsiteRecords cursorToWebsite(Cursor cursor) {
    WebsiteRecords website = new WebsiteRecords();
    website.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    website.setUser(cursor.getString(1));
    website.setSitename(cursor.getString(2));
    website.setUsername(cursor.getString(3));
    website.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));
    return website;
}
```

can you help me resolve the problem?

**EDIT**
so here is the LogCat:

```
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.bernadette.remembermypassword.DataSource.deleteWebsite(DataSource.java:56)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.bernadette.remembermypassword.PasswordActivity$3.onClick(PasswordActivity.java:296)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-31 08:11:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 08:30:21.998: E/Trace(827): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: We can't help without the error message!

Comment: updated. please see the logcat

Comment: I think `private WebsiteRecords selected_website;` in  `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` is causing the exception. You didn't instansiate it anywhere.

Comment: You should really learn to handle your own NPE (null pointer exceptions) and kind of plan your design when coding, it provides mroe context to the code and its implementation. @Ms.B

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found out what the error is. The error is in the lines with "(this.selected_website)".
To work that thing out, I removed "this" in the "(this.selected_website)" and it worked! Thanks for your help guys.